# Search by the nearest place using the completion suggester

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, full-text-search, distance

I'm building a search engine to find places from a huge Database stored in elasticsearch and want my results to be based on the nearest places from the user's position so I used the completion suggester method with its [context option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#context-suggester), but I'm facing a problem in the implementation.
I followed the documentation step by step but it always returns an empty array.

Here's how I'm creating my index:

```
`location: { 
  type: "geo_point"
},
context2: {
  type: "completion",
  analyzer: "my_analyzer",
  contexts: { 
        name: "location",
        type: "geo",
        precision: 4
    }                   
},
```

and how I'm performing my search

```
    contextSuggester: {
        prefix: req.body['q'],
        completion: {
            field: "context2",
            size : 7,
            skip_duplicates:true,
            contexts: {
              location: {
                  lat: 43.662,
                  lon: -79.380
              }
          },
            fuzzy: {
                fuzziness: "auto"
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please give same sample input (2 documents that shouldn't match, two that should match preferably